# how to get the starting text and ending text from image path in python using regex?

Tags: python-3.x, image-text

Here is the given two scenarios

Example 1

```
the Image Path is https://ictagrisindh.gov.pk/img/inauguration1.jpg the detail goes here
and the url was this and Click here to view the detail goes here
```

Example 2

```
https://ictagrisindh.gov.pk/img/inauguration1.jpg the detail goes here
Click here to view screenshot the detail goes here
```

My Code is Given Below

```
import re
 str_text = "the Image Path is https://ictagrisindh.gov.pk/img/inauguration1.jpg the detail goes here and the url was this and Click here to view the detail goes here"
urls = re.findall('http[s]?://(?:[a-zA-Z]|[0-9]|[$-_@.&+]|[!*\(\),]|(?:%[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]))+', str_text)
print("Urls: ",":".join(urls))
```

Result

```
https://ictagrisindh.gov.pk/img/inauguration1.jpg
```

i want to extract the text from starting point to end point between & also extract text from everywhere in image path

Any Help would be appreciated & thanks in Advance

Comment: write some code, test it, if it doesnt work, come back and post the code and the error or whats not working and i am sure folk will be willing to help.

Comment: okay let me try

Comment: can i achieve this using Regular Expression in python?

Comment: Its unclear what exaclty you want to capture here, maybe give an oiutput example of what your looking for

Comment: Chris Doyle check this now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import re

e1 = 'the Image Path is https://ictagrisindh.gov.pk/img/inauguration1.jpg the detail goes here' + \
'and the url was this and Click here to view the detail goes here'

e2 = 'https://ictagrisindh.gov.pk/img/inauguration1.jpg the detail goes here' + \
'Click here to view screenshot the detail goes here'

start_pattern = '(^.+)(?=http.+.jpg)'
image_url_pattern = '(http.+.jpg)'
end_pattern = '(?:^.+.jpg)(.+$)'

start = re.findall(start_pattern, e1)
url = re.findall(image_url_pattern, e1)
end = re.findall(end_pattern, e1)

print(f'start: {start}')
print(f'url: {url}')
print(f'end: {end}')
```

Example 1:

```
start: ['the Image Path is ']
url: ['https://ictagrisindh.gov.pk/img/inauguration1.jpg']
end: [' the detail goes hereand the url was this and Click here to view the detail goes here']
```

Example 2:

```
start: []
url: ['https://ictagrisindh.gov.pk/img/inauguration1.jpg']
end: [' the detail goes hereClick here to view screenshot the detail goes here']
```